# Pygame saying unsupported image format for png with os.path.join() I am following a pygame tutorial by tech with tim

Tags: python, pygame

```
YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(
    os.path.join('Assets', 'spaceship_yellow.png')
```

I copied the code from github and it still didnt work, I even reinstalled pygame
https://github.com/techwithtim/PygameForBeginners/blob/main/main.py

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69274983/edit) your post and add the exact and complete error message, not just a paraphrase?

Comment: "Unsupported image format" generally doesn't have anything to do with `os.path.join`. Speaking in general: How you form the path determines how the file is _located_, but whether the file format is supported has to do with how the file's contents are interpreted, which can only happen after locating the file happened successfully.

Comment: So someone making a naive guess (and we can't do anything but guess unless you give us the full stack trace) might think that the problem is actually that you don't have libpng installed, or something of that sort. (Or that the file is in fact corrupt and not a valid PNG file at all).

Comment: you should have your image in a folder named assets in your project folder

Answer (score -1):

Could be your picture placement. go to where ur project folder is. make a folder named assets and place the img in it

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer, insofar as it's speculative rather than authoritative. (If a question isn't detailed and specific enough to _allow_ an authoritative answer, that question should be closed, not answered).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy agreed, this should not be a post, such short answers can be made into comments instead and the question shall be closed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy my bad, i meant to make a comment.